# Identify what check has failed

Tags: javascript, load-testing, k6

I'm load testing a backend and have a couple checks to add to the error if failed. I'm able to collect the failed check and add it to the error collection but I would like to know on how to identify what check has failed and add a tag to the error collection corresponding to the failure.

I could see the Check() function takes a optional 3rd argument `tags` but there seem to be no example on how it is used.

Here is how my current code is:

```
export let errorRate = new Rate('errors');
export let checks = {
    'Response Time': r => r.timings.duration < 2000, // Response time should be less than 2seconds
    'status was 200': r => r.status == 200, // Response status should be 200
};

export default function() {
  let res = http.get('https://url');
  const result = check(res, checks);
  errorRate.add(!result, { type: 'failure type' }); //I'd like to set the type as either response or code here

  sleep(1);
}
```

Something like this could work but this isnt scalable meaning, more checks = more if conditions. I'm looking for a more simplified solution which could scale to number of checks easily.

```
var result;
  result = check(res, {'Response Time': r => r.timings.duration < 2000});
  if (!result)
      errorRate.add(1, {type: 'response'}); 
  result = check(res, {'status was 200': r => r.status == 200});
  if (!result)
      errorRate.add(1, {type: 'status'});
```

My ultimate aim is to record failures in influx database and store why it failed so I could add queries in grafana to show different axes for each failure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin k6 functionality for what you want - you can open an issue with your proposal :D.

As a workaround, I can propose that you wrap the check and have something like

```
function mycheck(input, checks) {
        for (var checkKey in checks){
                if (!check(input, {[checkKey]: checks[checkKey]})){
                        return checkKey;
                }
        }
        return null;
}

export default function() {
        var result = mycheck("something", {
                "first": () => true,
                "second": () => true,
                "third": () => true,
        });
        console.log(result);

        result = mycheck("something", {
                "first": () => true,
                "second": () => false,
                "third": () => false,
        });
        console.log(result);
}
```

Which will print the check that failed:

```
INFO[0001] null
INFO[0001] second

running (00m00.0s), 0/1 VUs, 1 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default ✓ [======================================] 1 VUs  00m00.0s/10m0s  1/1 iters, 1 per VU


    ✓ first
    ✗ second
     ↳  50% — ✓ 1 / ✗ 1
    ✓ third

    checks...............: 80.00% ✓ 4 ✗ 1
    data_received........: 0 B    0 B/s
    data_sent............: 0 B    0 B/s
    iteration_duration...: avg=263.44µs min=263.44µs med=263.44µs max=263.44µs p(90)=263.44µs p(95)=263.44µs
    iterations...........: 1      21.670176/s
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to manually increment the counter on failure, you can add the tags to the check itself and then filter on the tag value in the summary (and tags should also be included when a different output, such as influxdb, is selected).

```js
check(res, {'Response Time': r => r.timings.duration < 2000}, { type: 'response'}); 
check(res, {'status was 200': r => r.status == 200}, { type: 'status'});
```

And in your options/thresholds:

```js
export const options = {
  thresholds: {
    'checks': [], // overall checks
    'checks{type:response}': [], // duration checks
    'checks{type:status}': [], // status checks
  }
}
```